# Change vertical axis from time to number on timegrid

Tags: fullcalendar

How I can change vertical axis from time (6:00am, 7:00am etc) to pair number (higher school) (for example num1,num2,num3).

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i forgot to say, i'm about fullcalendar. I'd like to set on vertical axis no time, but number of events. It would look like screenshot above  https://i.ibb.co/BBJ8BgK/2019-10-28-11-59-35.png

Comment: You can't. It's a calendar. The whole premise is that it's based on time. Are you trying to make a school timetable where you show specific, fixed lesson periods rather than times of day? Maybe you just need a simple HTML table instead.